# В чём разница между способами добавления изображений на фон в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Начала изучать Tkinter, питон 3й версии.
Задача: Добавить на фон окна изображение. Не могу найти информацию о том как делать это "правильно".
Нашла 3 варианта:

1. Добавляем изображение в Canvas

   ```
   root = Tk()
   canvas = Canvas(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
   canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
   self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")
   canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = self.image, anchor = NW)
   ```
2. Добавляем изображение в Label, а потом в основное окно

   ```
   root = Tk()
   photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")
   w = Label(root, image=photo)
   w.pack()
   ```
3. Добавляем изображение в Label, потом в Canvas, потом в основное окно

   ```
   top = Tk()
   C = Canvas(top, bg="blue", height=250, width=300) 
   filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file ="C:\\Users\\location\\imageName.png")
   background_label = Label(top, image=filename)
   background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1) 
   C.pack()
   ```

Все варианты у меня нормально работают.
Если правильны все 3 варианта для моей версии питона, то в чём тогда разница между этими способами и когда какой лучше использовать?

Comment: Ничего не знаю, но я бы предположил, что нет смысла использовать canvas, если не планируется что-то рисовать (помимо отображения имеющейся картинки).

Comment: Насчёт Canvas спасибо, думаю Вы правы.
Мне ещё интересно нужен ли Label, для меня он всё таки всегда ассоциировался с текстовым полем на одну строку, а здесь в него добавляют изображение

Comment: Без понятия. Вообще на питоне не программирую.

Comment: `Label` будет более правильным, потому что в `tkinter` нет определенного виджета для изображение по этому как правило используют `Label` (т.е. как во 2 пункте у вас)

Comment: Спасибо большое)